# Persuading TSC that match array elements are known to be defined

Tags: regex, typescript, typechecking

Consider

```
function match(s: string): string {
    let m;
    if ((m = /<(wi+b*le)>/.exec(s)) !== null) {
        return m[1];  // [2332] Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    }
    return "no match";
}
```

A human can see that if the regexp matches at all, group #1 will definitely have captured text, and therefore `m[1]` will not be `undefined`, but TSC does not know that and throws an error.

Assuming project policy forbids the use of non-null assertions (postfix `!`), what is the recommended way to turn `m[1]` into something that can be returned from this function?

Comment: I can't easily reproduce. Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mbAR3N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  If you are using nonstandard compiler options (e.g., anything outside of `--strict`), please mention them in the question.

Comment: Assuming this is reproducible, I don't see how someone could answer authoritatively.  The recommended way to assert something is non-null when the compiler can't figure it out is to use a non-null assertion. If project policy forbids that, it seems only the setter of project policy could tell you what a recommended alternative is. Anything suggested by SO folks will be a workaround. Like you could write `return m[1]??""`, but `m[1]!` is a zillion times better. Or you could make a runtime non-null assertion function like [this](//tsplay.dev/m35nqw) I guess? What do you want to see here?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the [Optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) should work for you:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIZQgCwBQGcBciuUATjGAOYCUhxZliA3gFCKIkCmUIJS2A9AB5sAdxgBqAEYAqADYcqAPn5UAdBwAeHCHioB+VQG0AjAF1EevYgDkYOCnRZrAbmYBfZswgJcceatk4Cmw0DBxrQTEYaJj5RWsqKmdEfn5EACIomOj5dK8fPw4AoJDHcLgoTA4SBKSUtPS7BzC8oA)

```ts
function match(s: string): string {
  return (/<(wi+b*le)>/).exec(s)?.[1] ?? 'no match';
}
```

```js
function match(s) {
  return (/<(wi+b*le)>/).exec(s)?.[1] ?? 'no match';
}

console.log(match('<wiiiiiiile>')); // "wiiiiiiile"
console.log(match('other')); // "no match"
```